# Linux Audio Spectrum Analyser

Tags: linux, audio, software-rec

I'm an undergraduate student and I am looking for a spectrum analyzer (or at least a collection of functions) that will output the frequency range of a sound that is played, as an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just need [a library, GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-spectrum.html) might be what you need

Otherwhise these look pretty good:

- [Sonic Visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org)
- [Spek](http://spek.cc)
- [Spectrum3D](http://spectrum3d.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Audacity. Read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160726101020/https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/420_Field_Audio/FrequencyAnalysis/FrequencyAnalysisAudacity.htm).

And please clarify what you mean with Array? If you want it programmatically, then you can read [this](http://aubio.org/).

Comment: Since I would like the output of the program(or return parameter of the function) to be used into another program, I considered that this could done more efficiently if a 2-element array was used(at least when considering a function).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Gnuradio Companion with a very basic Audio Source -> Waterfall.